# Is it possible to create docker image with Quarkus and Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions, dockerfile, quarkus, docker-container

I tried to create a Docker image with basic Quarkus project (Maven) with the Azure Functions dependency (form code.quarkus.io). On docker build command in Azure Pipeline the following error appeared: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref e9...dg: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount.../target/quarkus-app: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount.../target/quarkus-app: no such file or directory.

I figured out, that on add the dependency "quarkus-azure-functions-http" (groupId io.quarkus), the command "mvn package" doesen't create the quarkus-app folder in the target folder.

It seems that a docker image cannot be created with the default Dockerfile.jvm. Did I do something wrong or did I forget some config?

Is it possible to create docker image with Quarkus and Azure Functions?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create docker image with Quarkus and Azure Functions?

**yes, it is possible.**

- Create `quarkus Azure functions` using two different commands:
- First, install `quarkus` using below commands(in powershell) :

```
irm get.scoop.sh | iex
scoop bucket add jbangdev https://github.com/jbangdev/scoop-bucket
scoop install jbang
scoop install quarkus-cli
quarkus --version
```

- Create function using the command:

```java
- quarkus create app <project_name> --extension=quarkus-azure-functions
```

[image]

- You can also create function using Maven command:

```java
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.1.2.Final:create -DprojectGroupId=com.example -DprojectArtifactId=my-function -Dextensions="quarkus-azure-functions"
```

- This will create the function with `Dockerfile` to build the image:

[image]

- Run the command `mvn clean package` or `mvn clean install`, before `dockerizing` the function, this generates target folder with `<project_name>-1.0.0-Snapshot.jar file`
- **Navigate to `src/main/Docker/Dockerfile.native`, modify path in copy command as `COPY  --chown=1001:root  target/*  /work/application`:**

***My `Docker.native` file:***

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.6
WORKDIR /work/

RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work

COPY --chown=1001:root target/* /work/application

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

- **Create and Build the Image using command** `docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native -t <Docker_Id>/<Image_name> .`:

[image]

- **Push the Image using command `docker push <Image_name>`:**

[image]

**References:**

[Deploying to Microsoft Azure Cloud - Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-azure-cloud)